# Can honda EB2800 run A/C and fridge?

Tags: air-conditioning, generator

Can a honda eb2800 generator run both a fridge and a 12,000 btu inverter A/C?

If not, what's the lowest amount of watts?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the nameplate wattage or amperage of the refrigerator and air comditioner?

Comment: I would need to look that up, but, generally speaking, how much would these two appliances use?

Comment: @rbhat impossible to say "generally speaking".   They vary greatly from "energy hog" to "very high efficiency"

Answer (score 2):

You are probably just going to have to try them.  Technically, as long as the frig is a somewhat standard size, it should handle them both.  Get the generator running good for a couple of minutes.  Using heavy duty cords that are no longer than necessary, plug in the A/C unit first.  How well does the generator handle it. Has the voltage dropped any?  Has the RPM dropped any significant amount?  If things seem ok then plug in the second unit.  See if it will frig run.  Do the checks on the generator again.  Try to get a wattage and amp draw on both units and work the math.  The one place where you will more likely have trouble, which is unlikely to happen, they both try to start at the very same time.  Good Luck. P.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Generally speaking, how many watts does a standard fridge and a 12,000 btu a/c use?

Comment: There are just too many variables.  There are no rules of thumb.  The best way to get them running on the generator.  And see how it acts.  Second, get them running and check them with a good quality Amp Meter.  Then to the math.  Finally Add 75% for starting current of the highest drawing load.

Comment: Make sure to follow the advice of using a heavy duty cord.  Many years ago after hurricane Andrew our fridge would not start on the generator with the extension cords we had on hand.  We ran 14/2 romex out to the generator and whazam, no problems thereafter.

Comment: 75% starting current is underrated, usually starting current for electric motors is about 5 times higher than running current, specially if started under load (like gas compressors)

Answer (score 0):

I say no as electric motors have high startup current, Your fridge will surely go, (1A running load, 6 amps starting load)  Surely not the AC (12kBTU @3COP means about 1,5kW motor [6A@230V]). You should check on your AC datasheet what is the startup current and get a gen according to that. An average unit has about 6x running current (in your case to start the unit you'll need about in your case about 35A@230V or about 9kW)